# How can I view iOS10 files (pictures) in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, iphone, ios

I'm having difficulty viewing ios10 files in ubuntu.

When I connect the iPhone I get the usual "trust this computer" message.

I click trust this computer and I can see the iPhone  but I am unable to access or even see any of the pictures.

Comment: Have you tried using ragnarok or gtkpod apps?

Answer (score 3):

This is a reported bug (see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666))

There is a current [work around](https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc) that requires rebuilding the libimobiledevice/ifuse package bundle.

If you don't know how/don't want to do that you could wait until the package maintainers commit the patch. It's currently unassigned so no visibility on that.

If that's frustrating, the issue is Apple keeps changing things so the libimobiledevice devs have a fast moving target. Unless it becomes a priority for an enterprise somewhere it won't get 'realtime' fixes. They'll get there eventually. In the meantime you have the workaround.

Comment: I should also add that if you want this to be worked on more quickly, you can notify the bug tracker that it affects you too by clicking this link (might need to create a free account) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666/+affectsmetoo