# Newbie with iPod music problem

Tags: 16.04, mp3, iphone, transfer

Apple began to suck worse than normal. Around 13.10 began a series of failures. I saved some music on my iPhone. I need to move about 30 songs from the iPhone to my Ubuntu 16.04.

How do I move music from iPhone to Ubuntu 16.04? Rhythmbox is not working, or maybe it is just my newbie vision.

Comment: Hi Joe, it would be useful to know which iOS version your phone is running. You can find that info in Settings>General>About. I'm assuming it is 10 or greater. To my knowledge, it's no longer possible to access music files from an Apple device with iOS v10 and above. If you have 10 or 11, you can still access photos. For iOS 10, see: [How can I view iOS10 files (pictures) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/888447/787506). For iOS 11, see: [this guide from Dedoimedo](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6s-ios-11.html)

Answer (score 1):

you could look into using Wine (a windows emulator) and install itunes to that. Then, I believe, you could transfer the mp3s from itunes to your pc. (I could be wrong here though, because I don't use Apple products and am not 100% sure as to how iTunes completely works).

Answer (score 0):

iphones used to work using the *libimobiledevice* packages. But with every iOS update these packages become unusable. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu, it's simply Apple refuses to play nice with Linux.

You could try installing and using the above mentioned file but from my experiences it does not work for music. I've given up even trying anymore, it's just not worth the frustration imho.

The best way to share/sync/copy music files to or from an ithing is to use a Mac or Microsoft device. Unless something has changed in the last little while, sorry but that is how it is.